# renderTemplate in a plugin for front end request using front end template

Tags: plugin-development, templating

I want to be able to render a template in the main 'templates' directory from within a plugin controller.

Basically the controller gets the url request, does some work and then renders a template saved in the 'craft/templates' directory instead of the 'plugin/templates' directory.

I have tried the plugin path trick mentioned on this page https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/templates without any success.

Any ideas?

Comment: The trick on that page should do it for you. Can you `var_dump` the paths to make sure they are pointing to where you think they are pointing?

Comment: The path echoes out where I would expect '/Users/derrick/Documents/wwwroot/iha/craft/templates/' however when I do $html = craft()->templates->render('test'); it always get a 404 page not found. I don't need an entry or route setup to the 'test' template correct? If I browser to local.site.com/test I see the test template.

Comment: Digging a little more into this. If I pass a path for a template that doesn't exist I get an error message "Unable to find the template “_test”." However if pass a path for a template that does exist, I don't get that error message but I do get redirected to the 404, page not found. Does that make sense? Right now the template has no logic in just a little markup, there's nothing in it to redirect. Is there something that needs to get returned from the controller method to prevent a 404?

Comment: Found the answer, you need to use the $this->renderTemplate() in the controller vs the craft()->templates->render();

Comment: @DerrickGrigg [BaseController::renderTemplate()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/controllers/BaseController#renderTemplate-detail) calls [TemplatesService::render()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#render-detail) internally. Guessing that you just happened to be triggering Craft from a site request when testing that theory. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Craft will only serve templates from craft/templates/ by default if it’s a front-end site request.

To explicitly tell Craft to serve templates from there, you can use [PathService::setTemplatesPath()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/PathService#setTemplatesPath-detail):

```php
$path = craft()->path->getSiteTemplatesPath();
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($path);

$this->renderTemplate('path/to/template', $variables);
```