# Render Template issue

Tags: plugin-development, templating, emails

I've got a plugin which am triggering emails from (listening to the `users.onSaveUser` event).

I am using a conditional to send two emails, depending on the permissions of the person registering the user.

In one instance am using `$email->htmlBody = craft()->templates->render('emails/employee', $vars);` which works fine.

However, in another instance am using `$email->htmlBody = craft()->templates->render('emails/prospect', $vars);` and getting the following error:

```
Unable to find the template “emails/prospect”.
```

Any ideas why this might be happening or how to get more useful feedback?
I have double and triple-checked the spelling of the files and they are indeed available in the file system:

[image: finder screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template path needs to include your plugin folder name. So in your case the path to your email templates would be `pluginname/templates/emails/prospect` and the path you pass to `render()` would be `pluginname/emails/prospect`.

More info: [Plugin template paths explained](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/templates#plugin-template-paths-explained)

But that doesn't explain why the first template path appears to work.

I’d probably keep the templates inside my plugin if they weren’t being used from the front-end. However, if you'd like to change the default template path to your front-end template directory [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4353/rendertemplate-in-a-plugin-for-front-end-request-using-front-end-template) will help.

Comment: Thanks Luke - have tried with plugin template paths but still getting error `Unable to find the template “emails/prospect”.`

Comment: Need to use `craft()->templates->render( 'pluginname/templatename' );` so plugin name and then leave out your templates directory. I've updated my original answer.

Comment: Thanks Luke! Fixed by updating template path:

     `$path = craft()->path->getSiteTemplatesPath();`
     `craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($path);`