# Craft\ConsoleApp and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getTheme"

Tags: templating, console

I'm trying to render a template from a console command, but i'm getting the following error:

```
Craft\ConsoleApp and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getTheme"
```

The code looks like this:

```
public function actionIndexTemplate ($id = null)
{
    $criteria          = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = 'products';
    $criteria->limit   = 1;
    $criteria->id      = $id;
    $entry             = $criteria->first();

    if ( $entry ) {
        $output = craft()->templates->render('indexer/Product', [
            'element' => $entry
        ]);
        $data       = json_decode($output, $assoc = true);
    }
    else {
        echo "No entry found\n";
    }
}
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
CException: Craft\ConsoleApp and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getTheme". in /craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php:266
Stack trace:
#0 /craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(390): CComponent->__call('getTheme', Array)
#1 /craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(340): CErrorHandler->getViewFile('exception', 500)
#2 /craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php(233): CErrorHandler->render('exception', Array)
#3 /craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php(137): Craft\ErrorHandler->handleTwigError(Object(Craft\TemplateLoaderException))
#4 /craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(131): Craft\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Craft\TemplateLoaderException))
#5 /craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(750): CErrorHandler->handle(Object(CExceptionEvent))
#6 [internal function]: CApplication->handleException(Object(Craft\TemplateLoaderException))
#7 {main}%
```

Here is the underlying error:

```
2016/11/23 18:15:13 [error] [exception.Craft\TemplateLoaderException] Craft\TemplateLoaderException: Ikke i stand til å finne malen “indexer/Product”. in /craft/app/etc/templating/twigextensions/TemplateLoader.php:123
Stack trace:
#0 /craft/app/etc/templating/twigextensions/TemplateLoader.php(71): Craft\TemplateLoader->_findTemplate('indexer/P...')
#1 /craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(312): Craft\TemplateLoader->getCacheKey('indexer/P...')
#2 /craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(378): Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('indexer/P...', NULL)
#3 /craft/app/etc/templating/TwigEnvironment.php(61): Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('indexer/P...', NULL)
#4 /craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(347): Craft\TwigEnvironment->loadTemplate('indexer/P...')
#5 /craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(253): Twig_Environment->render('indexer/P...', Array)
#6 /craft/plugins/indexer/services/Indexer_IndexService.php(136): Craft\TemplatesService->render('indexer/P...', Array)
#7 /craft/plugins/indexer/consolecommands/IndexerCommand.php(93): Craft\Indexer_IndexService->renderTemplate(Array)
#8 [internal function]: Craft\IndexerCommand->actionIndexTemplate('35262')
#9 /craft/app/framework/console/CConsoleCommand.php(172): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Craft\IndexerCommand), Array)
#10 /craft/app/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(71): CConsoleCommand->run(Array)
#11 /craft/app/framework/console/CConsoleApplication.php(92): CConsoleCommandRunner->run(Array)
#12 /craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
#13 /craft/app/etc/console/yiic.php(81): CApplication->run()
#14 /craft/app/etc/console/yiic(4): require_once('/Ind...')
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace leading up to that error?

Comment: @BradBell added it to the post.

Comment: Looks like another error is happening first, then the getTheme error happens when Craft tries to render the default "exception" template.  Try checking `craft/storage/runtime/logs` for the underlying error message on the first error.

Comment: @BradBell Looks like it's not finding the template, and is throwing a TemplateLoaderException. Where does it look for templates when running in the context of a command? The same call works in a controller. I also guess the templateloader should an exception in console mode more gracefully, as to not trigger the getTheme() error.

Comment: Agree the 2nd issue is a bug.  Try using setTemplatesPath to your plugin's template folder like so: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4392/57

Comment: That worked, by telling it to specifically look into the plugins template directory. Do you know where it looks by default when being run from console?

Comment: Either site or control panel template path... would have to dig into the code.  Can you add that as an official answer?  Will look into the 2nd bug.

Comment: Will do. I think it's useful to make this into a post about where it looks for console commands, so report back when you find out. Does it also make sense to make it consistent with how it works in a controller?

Comment: Guessing in the context of a console command it defaults to site: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/TemplatesService.php#L141